# How to use GWTQuery-UI

Tags: java, gwt, gwtquery

I am trying to unserstand how GWTQuery works, for that I am trying out a simple demo with the `slider`. As per the documentation at [Google](http://gwtquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/demos/GwtQueryUi.html) (the `slider` tab is on the bottom left), and using the class `AbstractSliderDemo` from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/samples/src/main/java/gwtquery/samples/client/sliders/AbstractSliderDemo.java), which in turn, is implementing the `Demo` interface defined [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/samples/src/main/java/gwtquery/samples/client/Demo.java), my `onModuleLoad` simply contains:

```
Label e = $("#slider").widget();
Query q = new Query();
q.setupDemoElement(e.getElement());
```

However on page-load, it is throwing a NullPointer exception. Can anybody guide me how to use it. Probably I am missing something here.  (I have added both GWTQuery and GWTQuery-UI jar files to the build path, as well as including `<inherits name='gwtquery.plugins.Ui' />` in the XML file).

[image]

And here is the directory structure of my project:

[image]

Comment: Please paste the stack trace

Comment: Gimme a minute, I will paste it...

Comment: added this  too <inherits name="com.google.gwt.query.Query" /> ??

Comment: Yep yep, added that also, even though the doc says it is not needed, the GWTQuery UI jar takes care of it. But I have added it..

Comment: Ummm, is my method incorrect. How do I then add the slider functionality, if not calling the method declared in `Sliders` from within `onModuleLoad`?

Comment: Sliders q = new Sliders();  put only  this line  and try once

Comment: Done that too. No error on that..:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23596/discussion-between-the-suresh-atta-and-cupidvogel)

Answer (score 1):

GwtQuery-Ui is just a wrapper on jquery-ui. That means that you need to inject the jquery and jquery-ui javascript file. Check the [getting started guide](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-ui/wiki/GettingStarted) og GwtQuery-ui

Comment: But I added the line `<inherits name='gwtquery.plugins.UiEmbedded' />` to my XML file, won't that suffice. I didn't find any statement like you have to include the jQuery and jQuery-UI files as well..

Comment: Plus, The Suresh Atta above said that it is working for him, but he didn't add those files...